# How to clear korean text in a textbox in windows phone 7 apps

Tags: windows-phone-7.1

when click on app bar button ..clear the text in textbox in windows phone 7 is not working.

private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

```
                txtMessage.Text = string.Empty;
                UpdateLayout();
```

}

Please suggest any solutions

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be (as you thought) an issue with the Korean IME itself. Try setting focus to it first:

```
private void ApplicationBarIconButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) { 

    // Set focus to the page ensuring all TextBox controls are properly commited
    // and that the IME session has been correctly closed.
    this.Focus();

    MessageTextBox.Text = "";
}
```

[Shamelessly copy-pasted, read here for a closer look at the problem.](http://shawnoster.com/blog/post/Unable-to-Clear-East-Asian-Text-from-a-TextBox-in-Windows-Phone-%28or-always-clear-your-TextBox-focus%29.aspx)

Comment: For improper korean text like "ㄱㄷㄴㅇ효ㅛㄹㄴㄱ" it is not clearing in my code. If i give the proper korean text like "정수연"  it is clearing.. suggest any idea

Comment: I'm looking around for some more information; all I see that (might) help is that you can also select the text... does selecting all work the same way? (I am unfamiliar with languages other than my own, sadly.)